# How to float elements to the center in CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout, multiple-columns

Edit: **I cannot modify the HTML page at all or else I will automatically get a 0.**

My professor just gave us this assignment where we add CSS to an HTML page. We have to follow screenshots, using the right margin, padding, borders, widths, and heights.

For multiple columns, he wants us to use `float`, which is all fine and dandy, but 3 columns need to be floated to the left and then centered in the page.

So while the screenshot looks like this:
[image: Example site screenshot]

My actual project looks like this:
[image]

How am I supposed to float these columns, and keep them centered?

I have set text-align for section#featured, but that only centered the text, not the elements. I can't use the `display` property, or I'll get points taken off. In the other screenshots he does not specify any margin or padding for the columns, so they are what they are.

They are `div` elements floated to the left, by the way, so their default display is `block`. Setting an auto margin does nothing.

Any ideas? Should I just stick it to him and use `display` instead of `float`? Because that actually *works*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the diagram.

Create a container to represent the dark blue/purple outline. Give it a size. Centre it.

Arrange the three side-by-side elements *inside* that container.

Comment: This answer is probably what made the layout above (heading and four columns) in the screenshot work too.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can't edit the HTML or I will automatically get a 0. This professor is real moron to be honest.

Comment: The diagram itself is confusing. I made each column 350px wide, and the height is auto. The parent element's height is auto, and I set it to 1130px. (I'm referring to the green container because it looks like that is the parent element)

Comment: Ah wait. I was thinking of the wrong element. I did NOT set the parent to 1130px. Completely overlooked. Marked your answer as correct, considering the fact that I technically did not even give the parent a size. So once I made it 1130px exactly, the auto margin centered it. Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You can place your elements in a `div` and center it using css like

```
#my_div {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I can't modify the HTML page at all or else I'll get a 0.

Comment: @RickyAYoder But you can read it and check out the class in which your Prof. placed the elements then; if it's an id, use `#` selector and if it's a class, use `.` selector